Automatic save without clicking a button
I need to implement a list of items in angular(7).
The list contains input text and remove button.
The requirement is to enable automatic save.
How to do it correctly?
And how to avoid multiple requests?
I'm thinking about reactive form.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Yes, use reactive forms. It provides technics to listen to changes. There you can implement the automatic save operations. Here you need to implement a specific pipeline to ensure everything is proccessed in the right order. Using rxjs operators will help you to avoid multiple requests.
